# how can I pass dynamically data to a knockout template binding

Tags: knockout.js

Depending on the chosen template I do not want to bind to articles I want to assign the according viewModel data myself.

How can I do that?

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate(), foreach: articles }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding the foreach with the articles property.
You could bind the foreach with a computed property that returns the right viewmodel.

```
templateData = ko.computed(function(){
    if(this.getTemplate() ==  'articlesTemplate')
        return this.articles;
    if(this.getTemplate() ==  'docTemplate')
        return this.docs;
    ...
}, this)
```

I hope it helps.